# Angular 6, Iterate over a deeply nested object within angular template

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-template, ngfor

I have an object from a service like below

```
  let obj = [
    0: {
      key1: 'val',
      key2: 'val',
      key3: [{
        key1: 'val',
        key2: 'val',
        key3: []; 
      }]
    }
    1: {
      key1: 'val',
      key2: 'val',
      key3: [{
        key1: 'val',
        key2: 'val',
        key3: []; 
      }]
    }
  ]
```

the index can be more than 2 arrays, it an be upto 10 or more. I need to iterate over the index and the keys/value of their objects.

The outcome should be 
key1: val
key2: val

and once I hit key3 the output should be
key1: val
key2: val

I've tried getting the keys for the obj using Object.keys(obj), but that only returns 0 and 1. How can I get the keys of the inner objects, and render keys/values inside of my angular template?

```
 <div *ngFor="let key of obj">
    {{key +': '+ obj[key]}}
 <div>
```

doesn't work. the additional issue with the template above is it doesn't take into account the deeply nested object and its key/value pair.

Any help here would be appreciated. If anything is confusing please ask for clarification.

Comment: Do you need to keep level of deepnes, or just want to iterate over all keys?

Comment: I need to iterate over all keys, and if one of the keys has an array or object as values, i need to iterate of that as well. 

My other option is to extract the deeper obj (since i'm using typescript) and maybe have an if/else check that skips the deeper obj in outer iteration and in a separate div iterate over the deeper obj. However, that requires some manuel work which I want to aviod. I;d like to keep everything dynamic and render the json object that comes back. Hope that was clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a example on how you can handle this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aczh2w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.html

Is this what are you looking for ?